# Vue.js this is undefined inside computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have following input tag with model `selectedProp`:

```
<input type="text" v-model="selectedProp" />
```

and I want to iterate through items like this:

```
<div v-for="item of filteredItems">{{item.prop}}</div>
```

Here's the script for the component:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      selectedProp: "",
      projects: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created() {
   axios.get(`${URL}`)
   .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.items = response.data;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    });

  },

  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      if(this.selectedProp) {
        console.log(this.selectedProp);
        return this.items.filter(function (item) {
          return item.prop == this.selectedProp;
        });

      }
      return this.items;

    }
  },
}
```

**Error**

> this is undefined inside computed property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use arrow function which has access to `this` object

```
 return this.items.filter( (item)=> {
      return item.prop == this.selectedProp;
    })
```